# I need help building a low-cost contactless water sensor

Tags: capacitor, sensor, capacitance, touch

I tried to build a contactless water sensor with some touch ICs, but all of them use auto calibration features i.e. they can sense the presence of water without contact but after some seconds, they get reset.

I can easily build the sensor with a microcontroller but I need to build one without a microcontroller.

I found this circuit diagram of a contactless water sensor on the internet. Is it good? If so, then can anyone explain how this circuit might work? Or can you provide any other circuit solutions?

[image: Contactless water sensor]

Comment: What are the two diamond shaped things in the water pipe?

Comment: @SimonB Those diamond shaped things may be the plates of capacitor attacted outside the water pipe

Comment: "I need to build one without a microcontroller" - why?

Comment: Is the waterpipe an insulator or a conductor of charge?

Comment: Define input and output with error tolerance

Comment: @Finbarr because I want a simple and low cost sensor.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 it is non-metallic water pipe.

Comment: A small modern microcontroller will almost certainly make a smaller, cheaper and more flexible solution.

Comment: @Finbarr Can you suggest me any cheaper and reliable microcontroller?

Comment: You could look at the MSP430 series, they're dirt cheap and some even have analogue sections for signal processing.

Comment: I don't have experience with the MSP430 but they are a 16 bit part and are close to $2 for one in an easy-to-use package. And I don't know the cost of development tools such as programmers, compilers, and debuggers. An ATTiny204 https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Microchip-Technology-Atmel/ATTINY204-SSN?qs=3HJ2avRr9PL4sNktqJqkKQ%3D%3D is about $0.65, and you might be able to use an Arduino platform for development. I use Microchip PICs, similar in cost, and which have inexpensive development kits.

Answer (score 3):

This was an early 90's design I used several times.

[image: Water level sensor with D-FF]

1. ST1 creates a high frequency square wave, anything between 100 kHz and 1 MHz is ok here.
2. This signal passes 2 delay gates ST2 and ST3 and feeds the flipflop CLK input.
3. The signal also passes a low pass filter formed by R2 and the sensor capacitance.
4. There is a *race* between them: If the capacitance is low, the high signal at the D input is ready before the rising clock edge arrives and the flipflop reads high. If the sensor has a high capacitance the filter delay is longer and the flipflop reads low.
5. Since the flipflop output is high without water, I added an inverter ST4 .
6. There is an additonal low pass filter R3, C2 to suppress EMI artefacts, that the sensor wire may receive. A human eye would not see this via LED, but other postprocessing circuits could.
7. The threshold level (=delay) can be adjusted by the rheostat R2. For a very big sensor area it may be necessary to add the unused 2 gates of the 40106 to the CLK delay path.
8. Sometimes a connection to GND improves the sensitivity.

With this method it is possible to make a simple 8 key touch keyboard using 74HC574. The keys are 1.5 x 1.5 cm copper squares on a PCB. However, variations in the supply voltage change the gate propagation delay, a variable battery supply detunes the threshold.

Comment: Nice too. There were also some good ideas ... in the "old" times ... :-)

Comment: I like the concept. I'll try it out. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should use something as this :

- **C5** is the capacitor of interest.
- **measure the capacitance between two "points"** (in the opposite position ?).
- If water not present: air (diélectric change -> capacitance change (in air = **x 1**, in water = **x 80**).
- **No DC current** is allowed through the sensor.
- Opamp can be replaced by LM555 or low power equivalent.

[image]

Should be adapted to your case, a comparator is needed for driving the LED.

**ADD-ON :** EE&O

- Opamp at left is the same function of LM555 (function is a square wave generator).
- Output is fed (through isolation capacitors C2 and C3) at C5 - unknown value - (capacitor of interest, which value changes if water is present or not, because of the change of the dielectric value of air (=1) or water (=80), between the two points of measure).
- The generator square wave "passes" through **C5** and its amplitude **Vout** (dependant on value capacitance of C5) is "measured" (parabolic detection) by the rectifier diode D2 and filtered by R10 & C4 low-pass filter.
- Diode D3 adds 0.6 V (offset) to this voltage (because the voltage rectified by D2 can be "negative", and I want a positive value if I would use a microcontroller with an ADC to measure Vout, as in my simulation.
- **The right part of the schematic** (D4, D5, C8, R13, R15) ... can be deleted.
- Value of capacitor C5 is measured at Vout

**NB :**

- "offset" can also be simulated by "adding" a known capacitor, in parallel with C5, left in place.
- As the plates of the "capacitor" are **attached outside the water pipe**, the dielectric of the pipe is part of the whole C5 (de facto, 3 serial capacitors), so the **global sensitivity** may be reduced.
- plates of capacitors should be better placed in front of each other ... (if the plastic pipe is thin).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am still a learner so it's little difficult for me to understand by myself. So can you please explain the diagram?

Comment: Added some explanations in answer.